# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "mobile-ffmpeg-full": In Podfile:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ffmpeg

[image]

I'm getting above error when I try to add **ffmpeg** framework.

pod 'mobile-ffmpeg-full', '~> 4.3.2'

**(OR)**

pod 'mobile-ffmpeg-full', '4.3.2'

**Frame work Git link** : https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

Comment: There is a 4.3.2, it exists (there is a release tag with that version). The issue is the last line. The 4.3.2 needs iOS 9.3. What's yours minimum required target ? https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg/blob/master/tools/release/ios/mobile-ffmpeg-full.podspec

Comment: Deployment target for `v4.3.2` is 11.0. So, your Podfile needs to target iOS 11.0 or newer.